# Running batch files on Mac

Tags: windows, macos, batch-file

I just moved on Mac and setting up my development environment. I just want to know if it's possible to create batch-like files on Mac.

On Windows I had a batch script, which first run encoding with ionCube and then syncs filed to mounted drive with Create Synchronicity. Now I also have ionCube, but instead of Create Synchronicity I have FreeFileSync.

I have created the files, which I want to run, but I don't know where to write some execution commands. On Windows I had following command in my batch:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/ionCube Pro PHP Encoder 9.0.2/ioncube_encoder56.exe" --exclude "*.*" --encode "*.php" --encode "*.php4" --encode "*.php5" --encode "*.inc" --ignore "*~" --ignore "~*" --ignore "*.bak" --ignore "*.tmp" --ignore "*.iep" --ignore "CVS/" --ignore "RCS/" --ignore ".svn/" --ignore ".*/" --ignore "*.swp" --dynamic-key-errors "simple" --without-loader-check --no-doc-comments --obfuscate "linenos" --replace-target --allowed-server "10.201.238.5" --ignore "@/CHANGELOG.md" --ignore "@/wms/" "C:/xampp/htdocs/dev" -o "C:/xampp/htdocs/dev-encoded" %*

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Create Software\Create Synchronicity\Create Synchronicity.exe" /silent /run "Code protected"
```

If you know something about using the batch scripts on Mac, please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a starting point you could create your project using the Mac GUI and then use the Export function from the ionCube GUI, selecting Shell script as the export style. It should create you a working shell script for your project automatically :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mac is a Unix system and supports many different batch scripting tools. The basic one, which is also found on most versions of Linux, is the Bourne-Again Shell (bash), which is also the default command prompt on the Mac (and most versions of Linux). Bash provides a fully-functional scripting environment that has seen widespread use both on and off the Mac. If bash doesn't strike your fancy, there are several other options, such as Korn shell, tcsh and Python.