# How to create an executable on Mac to run python scripts (bash help)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, executable

Sorry if this is an easy to answer question, but I have been stressing myself out all day over this simple problem. I have never used a Macbook before, and am unfamiliar with the inner-workings. I wrote a series of six python scripts that are meant to be run in series, and have easily been accomplishing this with a batch files on my PC. However, I have been developing this program for a Mac user, and have no clue how to accomplish the same thing.
I have successfully managed to get python installed as well as all of the necessary packages, and the scripts can be run one-by-one, so the infrastructure is there.
On windows, I have been accomplishing this with the following batch script:

```
@echo off
python outputnotion.py
python addData.py
python listAppender.py
python inputgsheets.py
ECHO Timing out for 30 seconds to allow Google Sheets to compute values
timeout /t 30 /nobreak
python outputgsheets.py
python inputnotion.py
pause
```

I have no idea how to replicate this on mac, or if it's even possible. The person who will be using this code is not as familiar with python or running the scripts, so the simpler the solution the better.

Thank you so much, as I have been scratching my head all day over this seemingly simple issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running batch files on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174780/running-batch-files-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the [makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overview)? It works on UNIX-based systems, such as the MacOS. I use them mostly to store snippets of bash scripts I use frequently.

- Make a file named `Makefile`
- Within `Makefile`, write something like this:

```sh
scripts:
    python outputnotion.py;
    python addData.py;
    python listAppender.py;
    python inputgsheets.py;
    ## This is a comment
    ## Sleep for 30 seconds
    sleep 30;
    @echo Timing out for 30 seconds to allow Google Sheets to compute values;
    python outputgsheets.py;
    python inputnotion.py;
    ## Invoke a pause
    read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue...";
```

- Now, using your bash terminal in the directory where `Makefile` resides, type the following to execute your scripts:

```sh
$ make scripts
```

Comment: thanks, will give it a go first thing tomorrow and report back

Comment: forgot to ask, what file format do I use for Makefile?

Comment: Just `Makefile` - looks bizarre but it is what it is :)

Comment: How do I make that file then? Wouldn't I have to save a text file?

Comment: Don't use `make` where a simple shell script is more than enough.

Comment: @vonbrand - interesting, where would you use a makefile vs bash, and vice-versa? Genuine question

Answer (score 0):

A shell script just runs builtin commands and external programs. You certainly can write a string of invocations to python scripts, not just compiled programs. The shell is really a full programming language, with variables, control structures and all. A bit quirky, but I've seen largeish scripts doing complex tasks (not that I'd recommend doing so, there are better tools).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I've seen a good bit of conflicted information on shell scripts (or perhaps I'm just uneducated on the matter) but could you perhaps give me an example of what a shell script would look like? I've watched like 4x YouTube videos on the matter and find myself baffled somehow.